# Program to print string in sorted manner of their inserted frequency

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

Lets say i have inserted
*asd dsa asd dsa kk km ka km kk*
so accordingly i want to print the O/P as:
**asd:2

dsa:2

km:2

kk:2

ka:1**

Here i am providing the code that i have implemented

```
    import java.util.*;
class Subex1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try{
        List<String> l=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String s:args)
        {
            l.add(s);
        }
        Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(l);
        for (String key : unique) {
            int count=Collections.frequency(l, key);
            System.out.println(key + ": " +count );
        }
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

but here the O/P is coming like this
**asd: 2

ka: 1

dsa: 2

kk: 2

km: 2**

Comment: An associative array or a hash map is what you are reinventing here.

Answer (score 2):

Use comparator to sort using `Collections.sort(originalSourceUniqueSet, new MyComparator());`

and implement comparator like

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>{
 List<String> originalSource;
 public MyComparator(List<String> originalSource){
  this.originalSource=originalSource;
 }
 @Override
 public int compare(String str1, String str2){
    int result = Collections.frequency(originalSource, str1) -  Collections.frequency(originalSource, str2);
    //if same frequency then sort based on natural ordering
    if(result == 0 ){
        return str1.compareTo(str2);
    }
    return result;
 }
}
```